# I need to create a complex SQLite statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to create a complex SQLite statement.

I need a SQLite statement like this

```
if ((part ==1 || part == 2) && isFree==YES)
```

I created statement like this

```
@"SELECT * FROM book abook WHERE abook.part=0 OR abook.part=1 AND abook.isFree!=0"
```

Could you check please. Is it a correct statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Comment: Just a question: Have you tried your Statement yourself?

Try something like: http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net (googled it, never tried)

Comment: @ckuetbach, I wasn't sure in this statement. I didn't tried.

Comment: I think your statement misses the parenthesis, like mentioned beneath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM book abook WHERE (abook.part=0 OR abook.part=1) AND abook.isFree!=0
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM book abook WHERE (abook.part=0 OR abook.part=1) AND abook.isFree!=0
```