# sql query if parameter is null select all

Tags: sql, parameters, where-clause

Can the following query be modified to return all records if the `?` is null?

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME = ?;
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can also use functions `IFNULL`,`COALESCE`,`NVL`,`ISNULL` to check null value. It depends on your RDBMS.

**MySQL**:

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME = IFNULL(?,NAME);
```

or

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME = COALESCE(?,NAME);
```

**ORACLE**:

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME = NVL(?,NAME);
```

**SQL Server** / **SYBASE**:

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE NAME = ISNULL(?,NAME);
```

Comment: This won't work if there are nulls in `NAME`. But for non-nullable columns this is the way to go =) (EDIT: at least not in SQL Server)

Comment: Beware that this can produce slower queries than conditioning the SQL to not contain the where clause when the parameter is null.

Answer (score 93):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE @parameter IS NULL OR NAME = @parameter;
```

Comment: How to use this in PHP ?

Comment: @prograshid - Just execute the query in PHP

Comment: I tried to exucute query string but its giving when accessing the result. Saying undefined function call fetch_assoc

Comment: @prograshid This has nothing to do with MySQL, you have a problem in your php code. Just ask a new question here about it.

Comment: If you happen to have other predicates (something) I would add parentheses to ensure the evaluation order is what you intend [see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or ] for example:     WHERE something AND (@parameter IS NULL OR NAME=@parameter)

Answer (score 2):

The foll. query will handle the case where the Name (table column value) can also be NULL:

```
SELECT NAME, SURNAME FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COALESCE(NAME,'') = COALESCE(?,NAME,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE NAME LIKE CASE WHEN ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE '%' END
```

This will work perfectly but it will return only the not null values.