# Select Statement with rows as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table `USERS` with two columns (`RID`, `USERNAME`)
I am just passing `RID` to get `USERNAME`.

I will pass 4 parameters as User1, User2, User3, User4 which has `RID`
Now I want results like follow:

```
Level1User Level2User Level3User Level4User
ABC        DEF        GHI        JKL
```

I have tried following query:

```
SELECT
  L1.USERNAME AS Level1User,
  L2.USERNAME AS Level2User,
  L3.USERNAME AS Level3User,
  L4.USERNAME AS Level4User
FROM  [USERS] AS L1,
      [USERS] AS L2,
      [USERS] AS L3,
      [USERS] AS L4
WHERE L1.RID = @User1RID AND L2.RID = @User2RID AND L3.RID = @User3RID
      AND L4.RID = @User4RID
```

It is working fine but it fails when I pass `NULL` for any USER's `RID`.
I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it using Scalar Subqueries and you don't have to care about NULLs anymore:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT USERNAME FROM [USERS] WHERE RID = @User1RID) AS Level1User,
  (SELECT USERNAME FROM [USERS] WHERE RID = @User2RID) AS Level2User,
  (SELECT USERNAME FROM [USERS] WHERE RID = @User3RID) AS Level3User,
  (SELECT USERNAME FROM [USERS] WHERE RID = @User4RID) AS Level4User
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
select max(case when u.RID = @User1RID then USERNAME end) as Level1User,
       max(case when u.RID = @User2RID then USERNAME end) as Level2User,
       max(case when u.RID = @User3RID then USERNAME end) as Level3User,
       max(case when u.RID = @User4RID then USERNAME end) as Level4User
from [users] u
where u.RID in (@User1RID, @User2RID, @User3RID, @User4RID)
```

Comment: Your answer was also helpful but dnoeth has replied first so I have to mark his ans. Thank u so much for ur reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/13474228/2478298 for the answer

In your case that would make

```
SELECT
  L1.USERNAME AS Level1User,
  L2.USERNAME AS Level2User,
  L3.USERNAME AS Level3User,
  L4.USERNAME AS Level4User
FROM  [USERS] AS L1,
      [USERS] AS L2,
      [USERS] AS L3,
      [USERS] AS L4
WHERE (L1.RID = @User1RID OR @User1RID IS NULL)
  AND (L2.RID = @User2RID OR @User2RID IS NULL)
  AND (L3.RID = @User3RID OR @User3RID IS NULL)
  AND (L4.RID = @User4RID OR @User4RID IS NULL)
```

Hope it helps.

Regards,