# Java native SQL query to display all values when an input param is null

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, eclipselink, nativequery

I have the following DAO method:

```
public String getSomeTable(final String param1) {
    String sqlString = "select * from table where name ilike ?";
    Query query = this.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlString);

    query.setParameter(1, "%param1%");
}
```

If `param1` is `null` or empty then I want to select all entries from the table. What is the correct way to do this? I am currently using the following:

```
public String getSomeTable(final String param1) {
    String sqlString = "select * from table where name = ?";
    Query query = this.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlString);

    if(param1 == null)
        query.setParameter(1, "%%");
    else
        query.setParameter(1, "%param1%");
}
```

But this is not scalable. I have datatypes like integer, date, etc. I want to know if there is a way to skip checking for that parameter if it is `null`.

I was planning to use COALESCE(?, CASE WHEN ? = '' THEN '%%' ELSE '%?%') but I think ? can be used only once for a particular parameter. The next one > I write is linked to second param.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql query if parameter is null select all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474207/sql-query-if-parameter-is-null-select-all)

Comment: Does the table allow null column values?  If yes, would the query need to be changed to:  select * from table where name is null

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: Yes, the table allows NULL values.

Comment: I am using Postgres

Comment: I believe you can use one of the answers in that duplicate question then.

Comment: @Julian It says cannot be used where name is NULL ?

Comment: Maybe it's because the keyword for that isn't the same as in MySQL, i think you should take a look at how to check null values in postgres

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121296/discussion-between-hexy-and-julian).

Comment: Sorry, i can't join chat rooms from where i'm at right now. [Here's something that might help you](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparison.html)

Comment: It is complicated because of using ? in the java string. I used COALESCE(?, CASE WHEN ? = '' THEN '%%' ELSE '%?%') but you cannot have ? more than once for a parameter.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you wouldn't just use code to detect that the parameter is null and issue a completely different query.  Having two queries should be easier on the database.

Comment: Also, have you looked at JPA's positional parameters?  Does it allow using COALESCE(?1, CASE WHEN ?1 = '' THEN '%%' ELSE '%?%')  ?

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, I use something like this, perhaps you can translate it to postgres:

```
DECLARE @variable INT = NULL;

SELECT *
FROM sysobjects
WHERE 
(1 = CASE WHEN @variable IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
OR
(id LIKE @variable);
```

Comment: Why not simpler: `WHERE @variable IS NULL OR id = @variable`?

Comment: @Shnugo -  Or even simpler: `WHERE id = COALESCE(@variable,id)`?

Comment: This was my first idea, clearly there are simpler ones.

Comment: @Nicarus, this predicat would not use indexes the way you might expect it. Read about *sargable*...

Comment: @Shnugo - In this scenario is appears safe as there would likely not be an index on this column (see question).

Comment: @Nicarus, Well, don't know... And admittably don't know the specialties of Postgres either... With SQL-Server I'd say, it's just a bad habit to kick, even if it might work in many situations... However, happy coding!

Comment: I think the problem is I am writing java code so if I use more than one ? it is mapped to param2 . So I don't the conditional clause will work.

Comment: You can use the above format to create a stored procedure in the database, and pass in a single parameter to get you the data.