# @Query Not run null condition

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-data-jpa, jpql

It will be simple, but I can not figure out how to fix it.
I want to select all records when query parameter "empresaId" is NULL not like now no record is selected. That is when "empresaId" is null is as if there were such a condition.

```
   @Query("select paquete from Paquete paquete where paquete.empresa.id =:empresaId")
   Page<Paquete> advancedSearch(@Param("empresaId") Long empresaId, Pageable pageable);
```

Can somebody help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474207/sql-query-if-parameter-is-null-select-all same issue but in different manner

Comment: Try  `@Query("select paquete from Paquete paquete where paquete.empresa.id =:empresaId or :empresaId is null")`

Comment: I used to like @Query(value = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User u Where (u.modifier != 'generator' or u.modifier is null) and u.type=2")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the easy way is to add an `or` condition checking if the param is null so in this case it will return true and all rows will be fetched.

```
@Query("select paquete from Paquete paquete where paquete.empresa.id =:empresaId or :empresaId is null")
```

If there are more dynamic conditions you could take a look to [Query By Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) which allows dynamic query creations.