# How to set Default Value of Parameter in SQL to ALL

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, parameters, default

I have 3 parameters in my table called `@StartDate`, `@EndDate`, and `@ServerName`. I am wanting all 3 of these to have a default value set to ALL.

Users have the ability to choose a `StartDate` and an `EndDate` and it will return all stopped services during those dates. I am also wanting them to be able to search for a `ServerName` and it will return all records of that `ServerName` no matter when the service stopped.

My problem is searching for a `server name`. Right now I just have a temporary fix for the parameters which would be that the default of the `@StartDate` parameter is set to the beginning of the year which is a date that is before any records were logged and the `@EndDate` is set to the current date. So when the report is opened it shows all the records of stopped services and then the user can adjust the start and end dates as they'd like. But when I search for a `ServerName` I want it to just find all records of that `ServerName` but it still just returns ALL the records within the Start and End Dates.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT ServerName, ServiceName, Status, Date, Time
FROM ServicesStatus
WHERE (Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate) OR (ServerName = @ServerName)
ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC, ServerName
```

So what I need is to get the `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` to default to all dates so when someone searches for a `ServerName` it will return all instances of that server in the SQL database.

I also need the same for the parameter `@ServerName` so when someone search for a time range, it will return with ALL the Server Names that have a stopped service during that time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql query if parameter is null select all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474207/sql-query-if-parameter-is-null-select-all) i.e. `OR (ServerName = IsNull(@ServerName, ServerName))`

Comment: Removed the Visual Studio tag as this is a SQL question that has nothing to do with the tool in which the SQL is being written. (Unless there is actually a thing as a Visual Studio Table).

Comment: I feel like it does having something to do with Visual Studio since I created those parameters in Visual Studio and the report I created is in Visual Studio but okay...

Comment: I've added it back. I believe, though, that this is an issue more about how to write the sql to deal with a potentially NULL parameter which is a pretty common SQL parameterization thing. My concern is that it will pull in the wrong "experts" to answer the question, but I could be off base there.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your default parameter values as `NULL` with `OR` operator on `where` clause.

If the user didn't use any condition, then it will select all datas.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = NULL
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME  = NULL
DECLARE @ServerName VARCHAR(100) = NULL

SELECT        ServerName, ServiceName, Status, Date, Time
FROM          ServicesStatus
WHERE         
    (Date >= @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL) 
AND 
    (Date <= @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
OR
    (ServerName = @ServerName OR @ServerName IS NULL)
ORDER BY      Date DESC, Time DESC, ServerName
```

Here is a default parameter [sampleFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bcbf1e78b5c511f95604658c6e05a7d7)

**NOTE**

Your default value can be other (like `'ALL'`) ​that don't have to be `NULL`. You can default your parameter.

Comment: Didn't work. I get an error box saying "Could not update a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and that your query syntax is correct. Incorrect syntax near '='. Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate". To continue without updating the fields list, click OK.

Comment: @derekg8881 I edit my answer.  Make sure the parameter datatype equal to your 
judgment columns.