# Using Like with and operator in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem with working at stored procedure and stimulsoft when using `Like` operator and `and` operator. Please help me. When I use this code, it returns a blank page in stimul, but if I change one of the conditions to `or`, the code returns all rows in database table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[reportedu2]
    @d1 NVARCHAR(50),
    @d2 NVARCHAR(50),
    @name NVARCHAR(50),
    @unit NVARCHAR(50),
    @semat NVARCHAR(50),
    @maghta NVARCHAR(50),
    @uni NVARCHAR(50),
    @field NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Tbledu
    WHERE (unit LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@unit, unit) + '%')
      AND (name LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@name, name) + '%')
      AND (dateend BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2)
      AND (semat LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@semat, semat) + '%')
      AND (maghta LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@maghta, maghta) + '%')
      AND (uni LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@uni, uni) + '%')
      AND (field LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@field, field) + '%')
END
```

Comment: c# does not have stored procedures. The code you've posted looks like T-SQL. Please [edit] your post to properly indent the code and provide proper tags.

Comment: Please also explain what an expression like `unit Like '%'+IsNull(@unit,unit)+'%'` is expected to do. I admit, I'm no SQL expert, but that looks like gibberish to me. You seem to be trying to accommodate null parameters to your SP, which I would expect would be correctly handled with something more like `@unit IS NULL OR unit = @unit`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql query if parameter is null select all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474207/sql-query-if-parameter-is-null-select-all)

Comment: my problem is some of my field may be able empty means in my report form user enter data to some field and some part of data

Comment: Also: `@d1` and `@d2` are **obviously** dates - so **WHY** are you passing them as `NVARCHAR(50)` instead of the **most appropriate** datatype - either `DATE` (if you don't need any time portion), or `DATETIME2(n)` if the time is relevant

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s

this is persian date i save it as a NVARCHAR(50)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to debug this is to try each condition by itself and make sure it returns the rows you expect.

If you are getting back all of the rows, the most likely thing is that one of the variables is = '', instead of the expected null,  so the like condition is , for example ...

```
(uni Like '%%')
```

which of course will return everything.

Comment: Correction: `uni Like '%%'` will return all rows where `uni` is not null, because `null like '%%'` will return unknown which evaluates as false.