# How do I show all records when one field is null in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have my code

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS FROM CUSTOMER WHERE NAME = @NAME
```

but the **@NAME** is an optional field for searching.

If the **@NAME** is blank or NULL, it should show all records.

How do I approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql query if parameter is null select all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474207/sql-query-if-parameter-is-null-select-all)

Comment: Hi @AndreaMugnai it does. thanks for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to do it the easy way. I would do something like this.
You can use the Function `ISNULL` to handle blank or NULL.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE ISNULL(@NAME,'') = '' OR NAME = @NAME
```

With this statement you will get all records if @NAME is blank or NULL.
If @NAME is not blank and not NULL, it will return all records that match @NAME.

If you have more optional fields you can use `or`. But dont forget the parenthesis.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE 
    (ISNULL(@NAME,'') = '' OR NAME = @NAME)
    OR
    (ISNULL(@ADDRESS,'') = '' OR ADDRESS = @ADDRESS)
```

Comment: Hi, what if i have 2 or more optional fields? say, NAME and ADDRESS?

Comment: If you have more optional fields you can use or. But dont forget the parenthesis. See my edt.

Answer (score 0):

It will not select all records if @NAME is null or blank because if the `WHERE` condition is not true, nothing will be selected. (The only way something is selected with your current query is if this `WHERE` condition is true. You will have to use a different query.

Answer (score 0):

You are best off with a straight `IF` statement:

```sql
IF (@NAME IS NULL)
    SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS
    FROM CUSTOMER
    WHERE NAME = @NAME;
ELSE
    SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS
    FROM CUSTOMER;
```