# sqlalchemy how to using AND in OR operation?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, mixed, parentheses

i need to do this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tbl_member
WHERE (member_type==1 AND member_status==1)
   OR (member_type==2 and member_status==2)
```

i've tried:

```
q=session.query(tbl_member) \
  .filter(or_(and_(tbl_member.member_type==1,tbl_member.member_status==1), \
              and_(tbl_member.member_type==2,tbl_member.member_status==2)))
```

and

```
q=session.query(tbl_member) \ 
  .filter(or_((and_(tbl_member.member_type==1,tbl_member.member_status==1)), \
              (and_(tbl_member.member_type==2,tbl_member.member_status==2))))
```

the query sql still like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_member
WHERE member_type==1 AND member_status==1 OR member_type==2 AND member_status==2
```

how should i do?

Comment: [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or), with [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241158/) providing a list of references for `AND` taking precedence over `OR`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The query is semantically the same because `AND` has precedence over `OR`, therefore
`WHERE Cond1 AND Cond2 OR Cond3 AND Cond4` will produce the same result as
`WHERE (Cond1 AND Cond2) OR (Cond3 AND Cond4)`.

Were you to try the other way around (switch `or_` and `and_` in your code), you would notice that `sqlalchemy` does generate parenthesis.

Comment: i think that the "WHERE Cond1 AND Cond2 OR Cond3 AND Cond4" and "WHERE (Cond1 AND Cond2) OR (Cond3 AND Cond4)" should be not the same.

Comment: sorry, you are right, i tested in mysql database. is the same result.