# is it possible to use or_ between filter_by

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this query, to check if players are in one or the other column

```
SELECT event_id
FROM schedule
WHERE player1 = 1 and player2 = 2 or player1 = 2 and player2 = 1
```

This is working fine, however I need to write this in SQLAlchemy, so I came up with following:

```
check_events = db.session.query(Schedule.event_id).filter(and_(Schedule.player1==form.player1.data, Schedule.player2==form.player2.data)).filter(and_(Schedule.player1==form.player2.data, Schedule.player2==form.player1.data))
```

The problem is that when i use another *filter* or *filter_by* the resulting query will have *AND* instead *OR* operator

```
SELECT "Schedule".event_id AS "Schedule_event_id"
FROM "Schedule"
WHERE "Schedule".player1 = ? AND "Schedule".player2 = ? AND "Schedule".player1 = ? AND "Schedule".player2 = ?
```

I also feel that my initial query can be ugly and it can be done in different way. Even though, is it possible to use *or_* 'between' filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to combine `or_` and `and_` and pass the result to a single `filter()`. For example:

```py
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_

(
    db.session.query(Schedule.event_id)
    .filter(
        or_(
            and_(
                Schedule.player1 == form.player1.data,
                Schedule.player2 == form.player2.data,
            ),
            and_(
                Schedule.player2 == form.player1.data,
                Schedule.player1 == form.player2.data,
            ),
        )
    )
)
```

These types of expressions can only be passed to `Query.filter()`. `Query.filter_by()` only accepts keyword arguments and transforms them into equality expressions (`==`).

Comment: yes, thanks. I found this answer also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215644/sqlalchemy-how-to-using-and-in-or-operation