# Trying to return a MySQL when the value is one of 2 OR and an AND

Tags: mysql

Ok I am having some trouble with this one, for some reason this is not working.

I am trying to get a list of trades made by a user or to the user that are still active.

```
SELECT * FROM trades WHERE active = 1 and trader = 1 or tradee = 1 ORDER BY trade_date ASC
```

This returns non active trades because the tradee or trader equals 1.
I have even tried other variations.

```
SELECT * FROM trades WHERE trader = 1 OR tradee = 1 AND active = 1 ORDER BY trade_date ASC
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The assiduous use of parentheses may help.

Comment: Understanding operator precedence is really one of the most elementary programming skills. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM trades 
WHERE 
    (trader = 1 OR tradee = 1)
    AND active = 1 
ORDER BY trade_date ASC
```

Comment: You could use `XOR` for that. Your version needs some extra parentheses also, btw.

Comment: What extra parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses (and read up on [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)):

```
SELECT * FROM trades WHERE active = 1 and (trader = 1 or tradee = 1) ORDER BY trade_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your two OR conditions inside of parentheses:

```
SELECT
         *
FROM
         trades
WHERE
         active = 1
AND
         (
                  trader = 1
         OR       tradee = 1
         )
ORDER BY
         trade_date ASC
```