# Part of SQL query is deleted when saving a View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have an SQL View I am adding these two lines :

```
AND (NOT((Segment = 7) AND (Type= 'Reserved')))
AND (NOT((Segment>= 6) AND (Type= 'NotReserved')))
```

The query works, but when I save the View, `NOT((Segment = 7)` and `NOT((Segment>= 6)` parts are deleted. When I change order of AND clauses, I mean change query to this :

```
AND (NOT((Type= 'Reserved') AND (Segment = 7)))
AND (NOT((Type= 'NotReserved') AND (Segment>= 6)))
```

then `(Type= 'Reserved')` and `(Type= 'NotReserved')` are deleted. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You probably have a semicolon at the end of the existing view definition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff there is no semicolon in the query.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a minimal example of the entire view that reproduces the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "save the View"? from where?

Comment: Which tool are you using to edit and "save" the view?

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio

Comment: Are you "saving" this as a file? You have to run the alter statement for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Are they getting deleted? [Or are they getting re-written?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22568604/2697001)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz from Design.