# SQL Server : select from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this T-SQL statement

```
select a.CODE 
from MASTER..MASTERADD a, MASTER..MASTER b 
where a.TELO = '18002000047' 
  OR a.MOBILE = '18002000047' 
  AND b.TPIN = '42589' 
  and a.code = b.code
```

AND

```
select a.CODE 
from MASTER..MASTERADD a, MASTER..MASTER b 
where a.TELO = '18001147722' 
  OR a.MOBILE = '18001147722' 
  AND b.TPIN = '56783' 
  and a.code = b.code
```

The first statement returns 1 result (single line) (CODE)

The second returns 'CODE' but repeated like about 9000+ times.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A few things you are missing some parentheses around your `(a.TELO = '18001147722' OR a.MOBILE = '18001147722')`, second I'd strongly suggest using `JOIN` syntax instead of using a comma between your tables a the join criteria in a `where` clause.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the [order of operations of the keywords `OR` and `AND`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241158/1445356)

What you need to do is add some parenthesis. You are most likely looking for this logic:

```
SELECT a.CODE
FROM MASTER..MASTERADD a
JOIN MASTER..MASTER b
    ON a.code = b.code
WHERE (
        a.TELO = '18001147722'
        OR a.MOBILE = '18001147722'
        )
    AND b.TPIN = '56783'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need parentheses around your OR in the WHERE part of your statement:

```
SELECT
    MASTERADD.CODE
FROM
    MASTER..MASTERADD MASTERADD
    INNER JOIN
    MASTER..MASTER MASTER
    ON
        MASTERADD..CODE = MASTER.CODE
WHERE
    (
    MASTERADD..TELO = '18001147722'
    OR
    MASTERADD..MOBILE = '18001147722'
    )
    AND
    MASTER.TPIN = '56783'
```

This may not address your problem however. You have two different conditions (different telephone numbers and pin numbers), so why wouldn't you expect different results?

Less importantly, I would suggest you clean up the syntax on your code because it makes identifying problem areas and later reverse engineering easier to facilitate.

Comment: Actually the problem is this
"The second returns 'CODE' but repeated like about 9000+ times."
So, I get the code = "same code" but it's repeated like 9000+ times.