# SQL bit is false

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-webpages

I'm having an issue which I've been trying to solve for the past hour, and I can't seem to work it out. I've tried Googling for an answer, but haven't found one that works in my case, or at least I haven't been able to get it working.

Here's my code:

```
@foreach (var row in db.Query("SELECT * FROM PersonnelFiles WHERE (Badge LIKE '#1003' OR Badge LIKE '#1004' OR Badge LIKE '#1005' AND Archived is not true) ORDER BY Badge ASC"))
{
    <li>@row.Rank - @row.Name, @row.Badge</li>
}
```

So according to my knowledge which is limited, it should now return all entries where badge is like "#1003", "#1004" or "#1005", provided that these are not Archived.

But when trying to do this, it gives me an error: "Incorrect syntax near false".

I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Archived is a bit datatype.

Comment: `Archived` is Bit/Boolean???

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Consider taking the SQL, and debugging it. In Sql Server Management Studio. Especially because there is no false in your little code snippet.

Comment: change 'is not true' to  '= false'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM PersonnelFiles 
WHERE (
         Badge LIKE '#1003' OR 
         Badge LIKE '#1004' OR 
         Badge LIKE '#1005' AND 
         Archived AND Archived <> 1
       ) ORDER BY Badge ASC
```

is the same as

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM PersonnelFiles 
    WHERE (
             (Badge LIKE '#1003') OR 
             (Badge LIKE '#1004') OR 
             (Badge LIKE '#1005' AND Archived <> 1)
           ) ORDER BY Badge ASC
```

What i supose you mean is

```
 SELECT * 
        FROM PersonnelFiles 
        WHERE 
                 (
                    Badge LIKE '#1003' OR 
                    Badge LIKE '#1004' OR 
                    Badge LIKE '#1005'
                 ) AND Archived <> 1
                ORDER BY Badge ASC
```

se [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

there is nothing like **false** in SQL SERVER Bit has 1 or 0 values

```
@foreach (var row in db.Query("SELECT * FROM PersonnelFiles WHERE 
    (Badge LIKE '#1003' OR Badge LIKE '#1004' OR 
    Badge LIKE '#1005' AND Archived <>1) ORDER BY Badge ASC"))
{
    <li>@row.Rank - @row.Name, @row.Badge</li>
}
```

[SQL SERVER DataTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187752.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, however, it gives me no errors, but rows where Archived is true still show up.

Comment: I will suggest you go to `Sql Server Management Studio` and Execute that SQL Query and You can observe Your Output