# Mysql not equal operator failing?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql table (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`emails` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`phones` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`history` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=259 ;
```

I have the following query :

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE emails LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%'
OR phones LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%'
AND history !='None'
```

This is producing 2 records:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`id`, `emails`, `phones`, `history`) VALUES
(118, 'PLEASE SET', NULL, 0, 'addr@yahoo.com', NULL, 0, 'None'),
(237, 'PLEASE SET', NULL, 0, 'addr@yahoo.com', NULL, 0, 'gomez');
```

but I was expecting the one with `history = 'None'` not to be included. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the different operator in MySQL is `<>` and not `!=`

Comment: Put parentheses around your `OR` conditions.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu: Both `!=` and `<>` are "not equals" in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organize your `OR` criteria in `()`

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (all_emails LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%'
OR all_phones LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%')
AND history !='None
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df6830/3)

Comment: Thank you very much! Why does The parentheses help?

Comment: @user61629 its regarding operator precedence for full overview checkout this question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly set parenthesis in your `WHERE` clause :

```
WHERE (all_emails LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%'
   OR all_phones LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%')
  AND history !='None'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Why does The parentheses help?

Comment: @user61629 : You are welcome.`AND` has a precedence over `OR` as a logical operator, parenthesis helps to avoid cases like you did have, when at first was evaluated `AND` and only then `OR`, which wasn't what you've wanted to achieve in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (all_emails LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%'
OR all_phones LIKE '%addr@yahoo.com%')
AND history NOT IN(
SELECT history FROM mytable WHERE history LIKE 'None')
```

Comment: Test Again (I Changed)!

Comment: You still don't need the subquery.