# Use of OUTER JOIN AND OR operators together

Tags: mysql, sql

How to use the outer join and or operator together with the conditions mentioned below

Table 1: `PERSON`

```
ID_NO         NAME
512           RAM
513           RAVI
514           RAMU
```

Table 2: `FORM_DETAILS`

```
APPL_DATE      STATUS  ID NO 
12/09/2009       A       512
12/08/2010       A       513
12/07/2009       C       514
12/06/2006       S       513
```

The query

```
SELECT A.ID_NO,A.NAME B.APPL_DATE FROM PERSON A, FORM_DETAILS B
WHERE A.ID_NO=B.ID_NO(+) AND
B.APPL_DATE>='12/07/2009' AND
B.APPL_DATE<='12/09/2009' AND
B.STATUS='A' OR
B.STATUS='C'
ORDER BY APPL_DATE
```

Produces

```
Error: outer join operation(+) is not allowed in operand of or
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your tag `mysql`, but the syntax is oracle.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a - sign prior to 'C' or should this be an = sign?

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a comment on another possible issue. I'm guessing you mean _OR (B.STATUS='A' OR B.STATUS='C')_ as the brackets make this a single predicate. Otherwise this would mean meet all of the conditions before the _OR_, or only meet condition _B.STATUS='C'_. See why here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1241158/201648. Gordon Linoff's use of _IN ('A', 'C')_ reflects this assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use explicit join type instead of `(+)`:

```
SELECT A.ID_NO,A.NAME B.APPL_STATUS 
FROM PERSON A LEFT JOIN FORM_DETAILS B ON A.ID_NO=B.ID_NO
WHERE
B.APPL_DATE BETWEEN '12/07/2009' AND '12/09/2009' AND
(B.STATUS = 'A' OR
B.STATUS = 'C')
ORDER BY APPL_DATE
```

Comment: so how come you are accepting Gordon Linoff's answer that came 1 hour latter?

Comment: I havent seen the time wen they all answered. I just pick the one in the 1st. anyways thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query to (if you want to stick with the old `(+)` notation, discouraged, because it's vendor specific syntax, and deprecated):

```
SELECT A.ID_NO,
       A.NAME, 
       B.APPL_STATUS
  FROM PERSON A, 
       FORM_DETAILS B
    WHERE A.ID_NO = B.ID_NO(+) 
      AND B.APPL_DATE BETWEEN '12/07/2009' AND '12/09/2009'
      AND B.STATUS IN ('A', 'C')
ORDER BY APPL_DATE
```

Better, if you want to write ANSI compliant SQL:

```
SELECT A.ID_NO,
       A.NAME, 
       B.APPL_STATUS
  FROM PERSON A
  LEFT JOIN FORM_DETAILS B ON A.ID_NO = B.ID_NO
    WHERE B.APPL_DATE BETWEEN '12/07/2009' AND '12/09/2009'
      AND B.STATUS IN ('A', 'C')
ORDER BY APPL_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a syntax which is deprecated for decades better use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.ID_NO,A.NAME B.APPL_STATUS FROM PERSON A
LEFT JOIN FORM_DETAILS B
ON A.ID_NO=B.ID_NO AND
B.APPL_DATE>='12/07/2009' AND
B.APPL_DATE<='12/09/2009' AND
B.STATUS='A' OR
B.STATUS='C'
ORDER BY APPL_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `+` syntax for joins.  Learn to use explicit `join` syntax.  It is much easier and compatible across databases.

You do need to be careful about where to put the conditions.  I think you want:

```
SELECT P.ID_NO, P.NAME, FD.APPL_STATUS
FROM PERSON P LEFT JOIN
     FORM_DETAILS FD
     ON P.ID_NO = FD.ID_NO AND
        FD.APPL_DATE >= DATE '2009-12-07' and DATE '2009-12-09' AND
        FD.STATUS IN ('A', 'C')
ORDER BY FD.APPL_DATE;
```

Note the use of `IN` instead of `OR`.  I'm pretty sure this has the right semantics for what you are trying to do.