# query in database fetching

Tags: php, mysql

Following query where I am trying to display post on my friends profile but it display on both of my friends and not friend from user table

my database structure is,

> Friends_details
>
> > Friend_id----Profile_id------Friend_with
> >        1----------------1----------------             2
> >        2----------------          2 ----------------            1
> >        3 ----------------         1 ----------------            3
> >        4----------------          3----------------             1
> >        5----------------          4----------------             3
> >        6----------------          3 ----------------            4
>
> post_details
>   post_id----------------     profile_id--------------- Frind_id
>
> > 1----------------           1----------------            1,2
> >        2----------------           2----------------            1,2
> >        3----------------           3----------------            3,4,5,6
> >        4----------------           4----------------            5,6
>
> Img_post_details
>   Image_id----------------   Post_id

1----------------          1
  2----------------          2
  3----------------          3
  4----------------          4

```
$fid[]=$row_post['frnd_id'];
//echo $fid;
foreach($fid as $frnd)
{
    $excludes=explode(',',$frnd);
    //print_r(explode(',' ,$frnd));
    //\$a=print_r($excludes);
    $query_img="SELECT * FROM upload_post.post_details pd
    INNER JOIN upload_post.image_post_details ipd
    ON pd.post_id = ipd.post_id
    INNER JOIN social_panel_db.friends_details fd ON fd.friends_id=pd.frnd_id
    WHERE pd.profile_id=".$rows['profile_id']." OR pd.profile_id=".$_SESSION['pro_id']."
    AND fd.req_friend_profile_id IN(".$frnd.") OR fd.profile_id IN(".$frnd.") AND fd.frend_request_status=2 AND fd.profile_id=".$_SESSION['pro_id']." OR fd.req_friend_profile_id=".$_SESSION['pro_id']." order by pd.post_id desc";
```

}

Comment: What result are you getting? And what result do you want to get?

Comment: What is the error/problem, its unclear what your asking?

Comment: i'm not sure that  IN    values is right ,  what is $row_post['frnd_id'] values?

Comment: Replace the two `pd.frnd_id IN` with `pd.frnd_id =`

Comment: what is that "$row_post" ? is that a result set? are fetching it from result set or u already stored it in an array?

Comment: When i run query from post_id [1] it gives me the correct result of frnd_id [1,2]   but when i run it from post_id [2] it gives me the same result of frnd_id[1,2] not from frnd_id[3]

Comment: @Omkar Have you tried replacing what i suggested?

Comment: @JoSmo Yes i do...same nothing happen..

Comment: So you want to display posts posted by you only on your friends pages? And not on user pages which are not your friends?

Comment: @JoSmo yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

You need to join another table to get the id of your friends profile. And when 2 people become friends, you should enter 2 values (for the schema you are currently using).

Example:

```
Friends_details
Friends_id  Profile_id  Friend_with status
1   1   2   conf
2   2   1   conf
```

This way it goes both ways, user with id 1 is friends with user with id 2 and vice versa.

```
$query_img="SELECT * FROM upload_post.post_details pd 
INNER JOIN upload_post.image_post_details ipd 
ON pd.post_id = ipd.post_id 
INNER JOIN Friends_details fd
ON fd.Friends_id = pd.Frnds_id 
WHERE pd.profile_id = " . $_SESSION['pro_id'] . " 
AND fd.Friend_with = " . $row_post['frnd_id'] . "";
```

Comment: No its not working its going on first row and coming with same result again in short  for second user id it shows result of first user id

Comment: @Omkar can i see the PHP statement where you query the data/fetch the rows? It's just a hunch... But i think that you are missing a loop. `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {}` and not just `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: $query_post="select * from upload_post.post_details pd where pd.post_status=1 
$result_post=mysql_query($query_post);$row_post=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_post);
$row_post=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_post);
$query_img="SELECT * FROM upload_post.post_details pd INNER JOIN upload_post.image_post_details ipd ON pd.post_id = ipd.post_id WHERE pd.profile_id = " .$_SESSION['pro_id'] . " AND pd.frnd_id = " . $row_post['frnd_id'] . "";
$result_img=mysql_query($query_img);echo "<br>".$query_img."<br>";while($row_img=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_img))

Comment: Its gives correct result for 1 and 2 row because they have common friends when displaying the third row that is the 4th user it displays the result of 1 and 2 row again plz help me

Comment: Updated answer working properly,but the third one which is not in my friend list its getting same result in my output

Comment: How does you database look now? Please list all values for `Friends_details`, `post_details` and `image_post_details`

Comment: Friends_details
Friend_id Profile_id Friend_with
1 1 3
2 3 1
3 2 3
4 3 2
5 7 2
6 2 7
7 7 8
8 8 7
9 3 7
10 7 3

post_details
post_id profile_id Frind_id
1 1 1,2
2 2 3,4,5,6
3 3 1,2,3,4,9,10
7 7 5,6,7,8,9,10
8 8 7,8

Img_post_details
Image_id Post_id
1 1
2 2
4 3
5 7
6 8

Comment: Just trying to figure out if i understood you right. So the `user_id` of the third user is 3 and yours is 1? And the third user can see your posts but he shouldn't?

Comment: By the way... Why are `user_id` and `profile_id` different in `user_details`? don't they serve the same purpose?

Comment: And update the data in your question please, because it's kind of hard to read here in comments. Thank you.

Comment: I Update my data in question...it work good still 3rd user after if i add 4th user its stop working 4th one and next all (5,6,7..) Cant see thier own post as well as friends post..

Comment: You have completely changed your SQL statement now. Please describe what you are trying to archive again. I'm confused. And put braces around AND and OR. Because AND has priority over OR, and will be executed first. Maybe this is why your query is failing. Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or