# Mysql query doesn't follow condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have the following mysql query, which works but not the right way:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`CriteriaItems`)
INNER JOIN `Address` 
  ON `Address`.`address_id` = `CriteriaItems`.`address_id`
WHERE `criteria_id` = '2'
  AND `status` = 'published'
  AND `mls_id` LIKE '%123%'
  OR `Address`.`address` LIKE '%123%'
LIMIT 10
```

The problem is that I see it returns results that also have "status" = "deleted" and thats because of ``Address`.`address`LIKE '%123%'` if I remove this it works, but I need this.

So it suposed to search in the address table as well, but only based on `` CriteriaItems`.`address_id ``

Comment: You need parentheses in the `WHERE` clause.  Or, perhaps `AND` instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because `AND` operator has higher precedence than `OR`, right now your query works like this.

```
WHERE `criteria_id` = '2' 
AND (`status` = 'published' AND `mls_id` LIKE '%123%') 
OR `Address`.`address` LIKE '%123%' LIMIT 10
```

More information on this can be found [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

So you need to use Parenthesis to apply the condition properly

```
WHERE `criteria_id` = '2' 
AND `status` = 'published' AND 
(`mls_id` LIKE '%123%' OR `Address`.`address` LIKE '%123%')
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `OR` with bracket:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `CriteriaItems`
JOIN `Address` 
  ON `Address`.`address_id` = `CriteriaItems`.`address_id` 
WHERE `criteria_id` = '2' 
  AND `status` = 'published' 
  AND (`mls_id` LIKE '%123%' OR `Address`.`address` LIKE '%123%')
LIMIT 10;
```

Consider also using `ORDER BY` to get stable results.

Simple bool logic:

```
p1 AND p2 AND p3 OR p4 is true <=> (p1 AND p2 AND p3) is true OR p4 is true
```

I guess you want:

```
p1 AND p2 AND (p3 OR p4)
```

Comment: You should add an explanation as to *why* this is the solution