# WHERE clause followed by OR then WHERE again

Tags: mysql, sql

I will post only the part of the sql statament that contains `WHERE` clause:

```
//Together
WHERE `energy_extra`.`PacketFk` IN('7')
OR `energy_extra`.`house_extra_id` IN('4')

//Not together (separate where statements)
AND `People_from` <= '4'
AND `People_to` >= '4'
AND `Size` >= '100'
AND `Size` <= '200'
AND `houseconstructiontypelist`.`ConstructionTypeFk` IN('1', '2')
```

I can't change the order of these lines because they are a part of a much larger query written in codeigniter active record with conditional statements. What I can change is the SQL itself.

I don't get the desired result because `WHERE foo IN ('7')` `OR bar IN ('4')` is followed by `AND` thus SQL thinks those further conditions are a part of the `OR bar IN()` which they are not. They need to start with a new `WHERE` statement and every line after that can start with `AND` again.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
//Together
WHERE `energy_extra`.`PacketFk` IN('7')
OR `energy_extra`.`house_extra_id` IN('4')

//Not together (separate where statements)
WHERE `People_from` <= '4'
AND `People_to` >= '4'
AND `Size` >= '100'
AND `Size` <= '200'
AND `houseconstructiontypelist`.`ConstructionTypeFk` IN('1', '2')
```

Logic is as follows:

```
find rows where energy_extra.PacketFk is equal to 7 or where energy_extra.house_extra_id is equal to 4

then check all the other conditions
```

Comment: where (... OR ... ) and ...

Comment: I'm sorry, do you mean something like: `WHERE (something OR something) AND somethingelse`?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical `OR` operator has less priority than `AND` operator - thus you're getting this result.

You need just enclose your first condition in brackets:

```
WHERE 
(
`energy_extra`.`PacketFk` IN('7')
OR `energy_extra`.`house_extra_id` IN('4')
)
AND ....
```

Comment: And brush up on SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or

Comment: This is it, so simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also put the first condition (containing or) to last as below : -

```
WHERE `People_from` <= '4'
AND `People_to` >= '4'
AND `Size` >= '100'
AND `Size` <= '200'
AND `houseconstructiontypelist`.`ConstructionTypeFk` IN('1', '2')
And `energy_extra`.`PacketFk` IN('7') OR `energy_extra`.`house_extra_id` IN('4')
```

Or just enclose the or statement in bracket to separate it from other statements as commented in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do where where in the same query (codeigniter does it (->where() ... ->where()) but it transforms the other where in AND or OR if specified), I am not sure what do you need exactly but the solution is make a query by hand and palce some brackets to separate AND, OR. Codeigniter active record it is not very good in that.