# Assigning null or not null via case statement in where clause - mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sorry if it is asked before, I really searched but could not find.

What I am trying to do is to assign 'null' or 'not null' to a varchar variable depending on a parameter in MS SQL. On the first one, The user would only see the description if he/she selects 1 as index. On the second one, the user would see the description if the year column is larger than 2005 for a record. The code I am trying is below but not working. Can someone help me on this logic please? Really appreciated.

Thanks.

```
--- First one---
Declare @index int;
Select * from Cars
Where Description is (case when @index = 1 then ‘not null’ else ‘null’ end)

---Second one----
Select * from Cars
where Description is (case when Cars.Year > 2005 then ‘not null’ else ‘null’ end)
```

Comment: you are missing an `end` on each `case` statement: should be `case when <condition> then <result if true> else <result if false> end`. Also, this should be `where description = ` or where description like `, not `where description is `

Comment: updated. thanks. but this is not the solution, just copy paste error:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First one:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cars
WHERE (Description IS NOT NULL) AND (@index = 1) 
       OR
      (Description IS NULL) AND (@index <> 1)
```

**Second one:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Cars
WHERE (Description IS NOT NULL) AND (Year > 2005)
       OR 
      (Description IS NULL) AND (Year <= 2005)
```

`CASE` in SQL is an *expression* and cannot be used as a flow control statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! will accept as correct answer in 4 mins

Comment: AND - OR - AND won't cause problems?

Comment: @Yossi I think not because `AND` has precedence over `OR`.

Comment: @Yossi Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or). Apart from that do you see any flaw in the predicates I've used?

Comment: No, I guess you are right, just asked:)