# How is mysql interpreting/grouping a duplicate WHERE statement with an OR statement in the middle?

Tags: mysql

I am using an Laravel's ORM. It is generating a huge query and inside that query I noticed that there is a WHERE statement that repeats itself, and the order of that WHERE statement seems to be very important. I believe it has something to do with how MySQL is grouping the WHERE statements but I don't understand how MySQL works well enough. I'm trying to understand why this works the way it does. How is mysql interpreting/grouping this?

**Table**

```
items
-----------------------------------------------
id       |    status
-----------------------------------------------
19       |    1 
20       |    0 
21       |    1
```

**Results needed:**

```
-----------------------------------------------
id       |    status
-----------------------------------------------
19       |    1 
21       |    1
```

The query is much longer than this. But here is the code the ORM is generating that produces the above results needed:

`SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE status = 1 OR id IN ('20') AND status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC;`

If I remove the last `status = 1` the query does not return the needed results. Is MySQL grouping the WHERE statements like this:

`SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE status = 1 OR (id IN ('20') AND status = 1);`

The query the ORM produces is a few pages long, so when reading this it is pretty confusing without the parentheses. It seems like MySQL is grouping it like this. I guess I don't understand well enough how MySQL works. Any recommendations on books to better understand MySQL?

## Building up the Query/Trying to understand what MySQL is doing

### 1)

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE status = 1`

**Results**

```
-----------------------------------------------
id       |    status
-----------------------------------------------
19       |    1 
21       |    1
```

### 2)

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE status = 1 OR id IN ('20')`

**Results**

```
-----------------------------------------------
id       |    status
-----------------------------------------------
19       |    1 
20       |    0
21       |    1
```

### 3)

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE status = 1 OR id IN ('20') AND status = 1`

**Results**

```
-----------------------------------------------
id       |    status
-----------------------------------------------
19       |    1 
21       |    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` has precedence over `OR`, see also [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or).

For your example, this means

`SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE status = 1 OR  id IN ('20') AND status = 1 ;`

is automatically interpreted as

`SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE status = 1 OR (id IN ('20') AND status = 1);`

even if you don't put the parenthesis.

It is a good idea to *always write the parenthesis*, even if you know they are not needed, to make the intention clear to other readers of your code (and to the compiler/interpreter, if needed).