# Combining AND and OR in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I'm having a hard time on getting the exact result in this query

```
SELECT isnull(SUM(a.Amount), 0) FROM tableName as a 
WHERE a.ProgramID = 4 and a.AccountID = 475 and a.ActionCode = 1 OR a.ActionCode = 3
```

My Table

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
|  AMOUNT  |  ProgramID  |  AccountID  |  ActionCode  |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|  500     |  4          |  475        |  1           |
|  1000    |  4          |  475        |  1           |
|  1500    |  4          |  370        |  3           |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

Instead of getting total amount `1500` I get a result of `3000`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Comment: Just to clarify to OP .. it's being interpreted as:  `SELECT isnull(SUM(a.Amount), 0) FROM tableName as a 
WHERE ( a.ProgramID = 4 and a.AccountID = 475 and a.ActionCode = 1 ) OR a.ActionCode = 3`  with the added paranthesis, you should be able to see why you got the results you did ;)  Ghost's and Gordon's answers below are spot on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use parens if you use OR.

```
SELECT isnull(SUM(a.Amount), 0)
FROM tableName as a 
WHERE a.ProgramID = 4
and a.AccountID = 475
and (
       a.ActionCode = 1
    OR a.ActionCode = 3
)
```

Or how I would write it:

```
SELECT isnull(SUM(a.Amount), 0)
FROM tableName as a 
WHERE a.ProgramID = 4
and a.AccountID = 475
and a.ActionCode IN (1,3)
```

Comment: I prefer your second way . Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use `IN` instead of `OR`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a.Amount), 0)
FROM tableName a 
WHERE a.ProgramID = 4 and a.AccountID = 475 and
      a.ActionCode IN (1, 3)
```

You seem uncomfortable with boolean logic.  I would recommend that you always include parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`.