# SQL Server LIKE, WILDCARDS, AND, OR operator, braces

Tags: sql-server, wildcard, sql-like, or-operator, and-operator

Need help with querying a list of names which start with either prefix1 or prefix2. These names should contain values ABC or DEF in their description(next column). Something like the below select query:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Table 
WHERE Name LIKE 'X_%' 
   OR Name LIKE 'Y_%' 
  AND NextCol LIKE 'ABC%' 
   OR NextCol LIKE 'DEF%'
```

The result set should look like below:

```
 |-------|----------------|
 |Name   | NextCol        |
 |------ |----------------|
 |X_BLAH | ABCandsomething|
 |Y_BLAH | DEFandsomething|
 |X_BLAH | DEFandsomething|
 |Y_BLAH | ABCandsomething|
```

Can this be done using multiple 'like', 'and' and 'or' operators with wildcards or is there another better way to do it?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Is the problem that `_` matches any single character? Use `like 'Y[_]%'` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were only missing parenthesis, you were on the right track.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Table 
WHERE (Name LIKE 'X_%' OR Name LIKE 'Y_%') AND (NextCol LIKE 'ABC%' OR NextCol LIKE 'DEF%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select Name
from Table
where (Name like 'X_%' or Name like 'Y_%') 
  and (NextCol like 'ABC%' or NextCol like 'DEF%')
```

Reference:

- [Logical Operator Precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241142/2333499)

Comment: Thank you SqlZim, the parenthesis solved the problem!