# SQL Server selecting a foreign key whose value doesn't appear for given conditions

Tags: sql-server

i am attempting to write a query as part of a music school which will select only tutors which are available at a certain time on a given day, lessons can be booked in blocks of ten twenty or thirty and as such i need to check either 10, 20 or 30 weeks to see if the lesson wanted is free on all of the corresponding days, the query i am currently using is not allowing lessons within the time period but should be allowing them on any day of the week except the one booked, i hope that is coherent

```
select Tutor.TutorId
from Tutor 
left Join Booking on Tutor.TutorId=Booking.TutorId
where Tutor.Instrument='Keyboard' 
    and Booking.StartTime!='13:00:00' 
    and '2017-03-16' NOT between Booking.StartDate and DATEADD(dd,70, Booking.StartDate)  
    and ABS((DATEDIFF(DD,'2017-03-16',Booking.StartDate)))%7 =0 
                   or
        Booking.StartTime is null 
    and Tutor.Instrument='Keyboard' 
                   or
       Booking.StartDate NOT between '2017-03-16' and DATEADD(dd,70, '2017-03-16') 
    and Tutor.Instrument='Keyboard' 
    and ABS((DATEDIFF(DD,'2017-03-16',Booking.StartDate)))%7 =0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your `or` conditions in parenthesis for clarity and to ensure that operators are being evaluated in the order you are intending.

I think you are trying to do this:

```
select Tutor.TutorId
from Tutor
  left join Booking
    on Tutor.TutorId = Booking.TutorId
where Tutor.Instrument = 'Keyboard'
  and abs((datediff(day, '20170316', Booking.StartDate))) % 7 = 0
  and (Booking.StartTime != '13:00:00'
    or Booking.StartTime is null)
  and ('20170316' not between Booking.StartDate and dateadd(day, 70, Booking.StartDate)
    or Booking.StartDate not between '20170316' and dateadd(day, 70, '20170316')
      )
```

Reference:

- [Logical Operator Precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241142/2333499)

---

> Note: You should avoid using shorthand for date/time operations, you should write your string dates as `'YYYYMMDD'` without the hyphens, and be careful using `between` as it may not be doing what you think it is doing:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)

---

You can simplify your query by using a calendar table or by generating a sequence of dates for the number of weeks you are checking for, and using `not exists()` instead of a `left join`.

In the `not exists()` we will join the `Booking` table to our list of dates, and check the `StartTime` for those bookings, for each `TutorId` in `Tutors`. This will only return those tutors that have no conflict with the desired schedule.

```
/* variables */
declare @fromdate date = '20170316';
declare @weeks int = 10;
/* stacked cte to generate one date for @weeks number of weeks */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (@weeks) 
    [Date]=convert(date
          ,dateadd(week, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate)
          )
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo cross join n as tenK
  order by [Date]
)
/* rewritten query to use not exists */
select t.TutorId
from Tutor as t
where t.Instrument = 'Keyboard'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from Booking as b
      inner join dates as d
       on b.StartDate = d.[Date]
    where b.TutorId = t.TutorId
      and b.StartTime = '13:00:00'
  );
```

Comment: thank you so much, as a novice i'm glad you're here :)

Comment: is there anyway the second query can be rewritten to ensure it checks dates in the future and past?

Comment: @jackward I don't see why it would matter if it was future or past, just change the values for the two variables at the beginning.