# SQL WHERE statement with OR or AND

Tags: c#, sql

I have this SQL WHERE statement:

```
WHERE code = @code OR approvedby = @approvedby AND [status] = 'APPROVED'
```

I want to display the information of APPROVED status either `code` and `approvedby` parameter is true AND status must be APPROVED but the problem is PENDING status will also display.

Can anyone explain if I have made a mistake?

Comment: Think you need brackets`WHERE (code = @code OR approvedby = @approvedby ) AND [status] = 'APPROVED'
`

Comment: It's due to order of operations - `AND`s are done first, then `OR`s, so your statement is processed like: `code = @code OR (approvedby = @approvedby AND [status] = 'APPROVED')`, and is returning anything where `code = @code`, since only one half of an `OR` needs to be `true`

Comment: Operator precedence for SQL is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have ambiguous logic in your query, so the computer is probably processing differently to what you expect. Try putting brackets where you need them.

```
A or B and C - ambiguous
(A or B) and C - A or B can be true, and C is true
A or (B and C) - either A is true, or B and C are true together
```

You probably want:

```
WHERE 
(code = @code OR approvedby = @approvedby)
AND
[status] = 'APPROVED'
```

Comment: Technically it's not ambiguous - the order of operations are defined such that `AND` comes before `OR`. So the way he has it written is processed like your third item, and anything where `code = @code` will be returned.

Comment: @RufusL -  you're right, it isn't ambiguous to the parser and will always be processed according to Order of Operations. The ambiguity arises from fallible humans who don't process query logic like a reliable parser.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you are just missing parentheses:

```
WHERE (code = @code OR approvedby = @approvedby) AND
      [status] = 'APPROVED'
```

Comment: [Yep!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql)