# query indicates an undesired event

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to make a friend search section in facebook style. But i just want to result my friends in a friends table. My tables are in this **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd6c86/13)** .

```
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db,"        
SELECT U.username
     , U.userid
     , U.userfullname
     , UT.username
     , UT.userid
     , UT.userfullname
     , F.role 
  FROM friends F 
  JOIN users U 
    ON F.userone = U.userid
  JOIN users UT 
    ON F.usertwo = UT.userid
 WHERE U.username Like '%$key' 
    OR UT.userfullname Like '$key%' 
    OR UT.username Like '$key%' 
    OR UT.userfullname Like '%$key' 
    OR UT.username Like '$key' 
    OR UT.userfullname Like '$key'  
   AND F.userone = '$uid' 
   AND (F.role='fri' OR F.role = 'flwr')
 ORDER 
    BY F.userone 
 LIMIT 10
") or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         $data[]=$row;
    }
    if(!empty($data)) { 
     return $data;
    }
```

User id(`$uid`) of the person searching is `1` and the key is for example aziz because of azizs' `userid` is `2` and if you check the friends table `userone`(`1`) and `usertwo`(`2`) are friends on there. How can we know they are friend because of the `role` is `fri`. You can see it in the **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd6c86/13)** page also.

Now, what is the problem! The problem is when $uid(1) search his/her friend the query showing also role ='me' but i just want to show `F.role='fri' OR F.role = 'flwr'` . What is the problem in my query.

Comment: Have a look at (e.g.) [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241142/6248528) and then add some   parenthesis, they are not that expensive.

Comment: You've wisely used parentheses for the role condition, but not for the userone condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
SELECT U.username
     , U.userid
     , U.userfullname
     , UT.username
     , UT.userid
     , UT.userfullname
     , F.role 
  FROM friends F 
  JOIN users U 
    ON F.userone = U.userid
  JOIN users UT 
    ON F.usertwo = UT.userid
 WHERE (
       U.username Like '%$key' 
    OR UT.userfullname Like '$key%' 
    OR UT.username Like '$key%' 
    OR UT.userfullname Like '%$key' 
    OR UT.username Like '$key' 
    OR UT.userfullname Like '$key' 
     ) 
   AND F.userone = '$uid' 
   AND F.role IN('fri','flwr')
 ORDER 
    BY F.userone 
 LIMIT 10
```

Note that you remain open to injection with this approach.

Comment: you are talking about $uid and $key for injection ? If yes no problem i can fix it. If not please tell me why you said that ?

Comment: Dear Can you explain me about injection, please ?

Comment: Yep. You nailed it.