# How can I write case expression/If-then to create a categorical variable that accepts the specified conditions correctly?

Tags: sql, if-statement, switch-statement, tableau-api

I'm currently working on a project that would be super enhanced if I can get this SQL right! I want to SELECT various variables surrounding vehicles to represent as a table in Tableau, but when creating a calculated field (in tableau) and using If-then conditional format, the THEN options aren't all being displayed within the graphic and some results are even being incorrectly represented by certain options!

For example:

The below skeleton statement creates a field called MissingNumber wherein if "-----1" is true then MissingNumber will take the value 'Number 1'.

```
          If ------1 Then 'Number 1'
             ELSEIF
          If ------2 Then 'Number 2'
             ELSEIF
          If ------3 Then 'Number 3'
             ELSEIF
          If ------4 Then 'Number 4'
             ELSE 'Number 5'
          END
```

Continuing with the above format as guide, 'Number 1', 'Number 2', and 'Number 5' are represented categorically but NOT 'Number 3' or 'Number 4' even though I know that the data satisfies 'Number 3' and 'Number 4' too in quite a few records!

I believe that there is an issue with order here (or some other unforeseen problem) so I tried using a case statement:

```
    CASE 
         WHEN (Rtrim((v.plt_no)) is null) or (Rtrim(v.plt_no = '')) THEN "Plate Only" 

         WHEN (v.rnw_dt is null) THEN "Expiration Only"

         WHEN ((DocumentTemplate is null) or (DocumentTemplate = '')) THEN "Registration Only"

         WHEN (Rtrim((v.plt_no)) is null or Rtrim(v.plt_no = '')) AND (v.rnw_dt is null) THEN "Plate & Expiration"

         WHEN (Rtrim((v.plt_no)) is null or Rtrim(v.plt_no = '')) AND ((DocumentTemplate is null) or (DocumentTemplate = '')) THEN "Plate & Registration"

         WHEN (v.rnw_dt is null) AND ((DocumentTemplate is null) or (DocumentTemplate = '')) THEN "Expiration & Registration"

    ELSE "All Good"

END AS MissingInfo
```

My QUESTION IS: What advice does the community have about whether I should continue trying the IF-Then format within tableau, or building the variable Missing Info within SQL?

ALSO with the suggested choice, how can I affect the code such that ALL options are correctly represented by a crosstab ("MissingInfo" on row side, "License Plate State" on column side). I have linked a snip of the code and a cross-tab example for reference! Please let me know if there will be anything else I'll need to include to make this more clear! **NOTE in the Tableau image "Plate Only" does NOT show up on the graphic!

[Code-SNIP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMjUt.png)

[Tableau-CrossTab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bREfX.png)

[ResultSet for 'Plate Only'test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSZFj.png)

--The results are unexpected because plt_no is missing (what we want) but the document template field is NULL in 3 records. In that case, the 3 NULLs in the DocumentTemplate field should qualify those records as 'Plate and Registration Only' within the MissingInfo variable

Comment: <case-statement> _do not use this tag, use [tag:switch-statement]._

Comment: Those are `case` _expressions_...

Comment: Thanks for your help....

Comment: First, your image of the calculated field logic does not have a line for "Plate and Registration Only" as specified in the last sentence of your posting. Second, the logic order of operations in the first IF statement is a bit unclear. You can make it clearer by putting parenthesis around the OR and AND statements to better document what order you want the boolean expressions evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You have (basically)

> "condition1 OR condition2 AND condition3"

which is [evaluated as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

> "condition1 OR ( condition2 AND condition3 )".

Add parentheses to make that

> "( condition1 OR condition2 ) AND condition3" .

Personally, when I have a combination of `AND` and `OR` in a condition, I *always* use parentheses to make the evaluation order clear, even if they are not strictly required.