# Where clause only return one condition instead two using OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple select statement like:

```
SELECT *
FROM [customer] AS [c]
    INNER JOIN [customertype] AS [ct] ON [c].[CustTypeKey] = [ct].[CustTypeKey]
    INNER JOIN [ProjectCustomer] AS [pc] ON [c].[CustomerKey] = [pc].[CustomerKey]
    INNER JOIN [Project] AS [p] ON [pc].[ProjectKey] = [p].[ProjectKey]
    INNER JOIN [Address] AS [A] ON [P].ProjectGuid = [A]. [AddressGuid]
WHERE [ct].[CustTypeKey] = 7
    AND [c].[Name] = 'Customer'
    AND [A].[RegionKey] = 2
    OR [A].[RegionKey] = 3
```

For some reason the `WHERE` clause is not working correctly. I filter by `[A].[RegionKey] = 2` and `[A].[RegionKey] = 3`. So I want to get all items who have `RegionKey` 2 and 3, but it only get values with `RegionKey` 3, and I'm sure I have items with `RegionKey` 2 too.

What am I doing wrong with this `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Comment: Check out the link @RyanC added.  Just tweak your where clause and put parentheses around your regionkey ([A].[RegionKey] = 2 OR [A].[RegionKey] = 3) or simply use [A].[RegionKey] IN (2,3) which might be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
AND [A].[RegionKey] = 2
   OR [A].[RegionKey] = 3
```

to this:

```
AND ([A].[RegionKey] = 2
   OR [A].[RegionKey] = 3)
```

or this:

```
AND [A].[RegionKey] IN (2,3)
```

Then make sure the other conditions in the `WHERE` clause are correct, as it's likely at least one of them is over-filtering.

Comment: When I do that I don't receive any results

Comment: Correct. You may have records where the `RegionKey` is `2`, but you don't have any where RegionKey is 2 **AND** all of the conditions are on the other tables are true.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
                    *
                    FROM [customer] AS [c]
                        INNER JOIN [customertype] AS [ct] ON [c].[CustTypeKey] = [ct].[CustTypeKey]
                        INNER JOIN [ProjectCustomer] AS [pc] ON [c].[CustomerKey] = [pc].[CustomerKey]
                        INNER JOIN [Project] AS [p] ON [pc].[ProjectKey] = [p].[ProjectKey]
                        INNER JOIN [Address] AS [A] ON [P].ProjectGuid = [A]. [AddressGuid]
                    WHERE [ct].[CustTypeKey] = 7
                        AND [c].[Name] = 'Customer'
                         AND ([A].[RegionKey] = 2 OR [A].[RegionKey] = 3)
```

You need to add () around the two items to be affected by the OR clause. Right now the OR clause is invalidating the previous AND statements.

Your previous query was saying this in plain english:
"Return all the results that have a custtype key of 7 AND a name of Customer AND a Region key of 2, or just the results that have a region key of 3 (so if the region key is 3, they don't have to be a customer or have a custtype of 7).

Your code should run correctly now.

Comment: When I do that I don't receive any results

Comment: I don't think you have any customers with a custtypekey of 7 and name of customer and regionkey of 2. It would show up otherwise. Possibly the INNER JOINS are an issue? Do any of customers with a region key 2 not exists in any of the tables? The INNER JOINS mean the customers details must exist in all the tables, not just one.