# How to write SQL query with LIKE operator

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a SQL query to get the data from the database but it doesn't execute properly. Everything works properly until I add the part

```
AND adstatus='success'
```

There is no problem executing the query. The problem is `adstatus` equals to `pending` in database, but still it gives all the results when `adstatus` is set to `success` in the query with `LIKE` operators.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE adtitle LIKE '%$keyword%' OR addescription LIKE '%$keyword%' OR adcontactemail LIKE '%$keyword%' AND adstatus='success'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($queryResult > 0) {
    echo 'Results found: '.$queryResult;
} else {
    echo 'No results matching your serach!';
}
?>
```

`$queryResult` values should be less than 0 since `adstatus` value in database is `pending` but still it prints:

> ```
> Results found: 3
> ```

How to write SQL with both `LIKE` operator and a `WHERE` condition like above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE adstatus='success'
 AND  ( adtitle LIKE '%$keyword%' OR addescription LIKE '%$keyword%' OR adcontactemail LIKE '%$keyword%' )";
```

> The MySQL AND & OR conditions allow you to test multiple conditions.
>   Don't forget the order of operation parentheses!

Answer (score 1):

The OR condition should be inside the parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM ad WHERE 
adstatus='success' AND 
(adtitle LIKE '%$keyword%') OR 
(addescription LIKE '%$keyword%') OR 
(adcontactemail LIKE '%$keyword%')
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Query:

sql = "SELECT * FROM ad WHERE adtitle LIKE '%$keyword%' OR addescription LIKE '%$keyword%' OR adcontactemail LIKE '%$keyword%' AND adstatus='success'";

1. exp1 = { adtitle LIKE '%$keyword%' }
2. exp2 = { addescription LIKE  '%$keyword%' }
3. exp3 = { adcontactemail LIKE '%$keyword%' }
4. exp4 = { adstatus='success' }

So, you have :

- exp1 OR exp2 OR exp3 AND exp4

And has precedence over Or [to see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

That means, it will be executed like :

- exp1 OR ( exp2 OR (exp3 AND exp4) )

To achieve your need, you have to write like :

- **exp4 AND (exp1 OR exp2 OR exp3)**