# Incorrect output for the desired question

Tags: mysql, sql, string

The aim is to query all CITIES with both the starting and ending alphabet being a vowel. I tried the code below which doesn't seem to work. Can you explain why it doesn't work? Is there a better way?

I have tried to first get the cities which end in a vowel and then try to use it as a subquery for selecting cities that start in a vowel, as below

I have already tried implementing this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CITY)
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY LIKE 'a%'
  OR CITY LIKE 'e%'
  OR CITY LIKE 'i%'
  OR CITY LIKE 'o%'
  OR CITY LIKE 'u%'
AND CITY IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT(CITY)
  FROM STATION
  WHERE CITY LIKE '%a'
    OR CITY LIKE '%e'
    OR CITY LIKE '%i'
    OR CITY LIKE '%o'
    OR CITY LIKE '%u'
);
```

The needed output is something like:

```
Oslo
Upperco
Amazonia
...
...
...
```

I am getting these as output as well as those cities that don't end in a vowel like:

```
Arlington 
Albany 
Upperco 
Aguanga 
Odin 
East China 
Algonac 
Onaway 
Irvington 
Arrowsmith 
Oakfield 
Elkton 
East Irvine 
Amo 
...
...
...
```

Comment: AND binds tighter than OR. Your code means ... OR ... OR (... AND ...). You want (... OR ... OR ...) AND ... PS Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen That is not a duplicate of this question. This question is asking about what their bug is, not ways to code their goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1241142/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

A better way might be to use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE CITY REGEXP '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$';
```

Note that `REGEXP` is not case sensitive, so we only need to use `[aeiou]` in a single case, in the regular expression.

Your current query is actually logically correct, but won't give you the behavior your want due to incorrect use/understanding of `AND` and `OR`.  `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so you are missing some parentheses in your query.  Try this version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE
    (LOWER(CITY) LIKE 'a%' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE 'e%' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE 'i%' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE 'o%' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE 'u%') AND
    (LOWER(CITY) LIKE '%a' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE '%e' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE '%i' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE '%o' OR
     LOWER(CITY) LIKE '%u') ;
```

Comment: What is "logically correct" supposed to mean? PS Why do you hammer a post to prevent others from answering yet answer? Why do you answer about precedence when that is an obvious duplicate?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: You click up arrow, I get points.  It is simple.

Comment: This answer post merits a downvote since the question is a duplicate (but not of the one you linked) & so does hammering & answering.