# How do i use and with multiple or condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

my target where qq blank AND match ab with OR condition.

```
SELECT
    xyz
FROM
    admin 
WHERE
    qq = ''
    AND ab LIKE 'some1' 
    OR ab LIKE 'some2' 
    OR ab LIKE 'some3'
```

Comment: You have a table called 'col'?

Comment: The requirement is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you share some sample data and the result you want to get for it?

Comment: sorry, just edited

Comment: What has stopped you from reading about precedence of OR & AND in SQL? (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your collation, this particular query can be written like this:

```
SELECT xyz
 FROM col_admin 
WHERE qq = ''
  AND ab IN('some1','some2','some3')
```

More generally, the astute use of parentheses will suffice...

```
SELECT xyz
  FROM col_admin 
 WHERE qq = ''
   AND ( ab LIKE 'some1' 
      OR ab LIKE 'some2' 
      OR ab LIKE 'some3'
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

The script syntax will be as follow. This will ensure the QQ Is blank and ab match any of the text.

```
SELECT xyz
FROM col_admin 
WHERE qq = ''
AND (ab LIKE '%some1%' OR ab LIKE '%some2%'  OR ab LIKE '%some3%')
```

Comment: yeh, sure, i will when stackoverflow make me as a moderator :P and the moment my permission to view only. hehe

Answer (score 1):

Use `in`:

```
WHERE qq = '' AND ab IN ('some1', 'some2', 'some3')
```

You are not using wildcards, so there is no need to use `LIKE`.

You don't seem to understand how `AND` and `OR` work together.  Because you don't understand precedence (yet), use parentheses whenever your conditions have both `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: (Well, depending on collation)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by putting braces in the condition

```
SELECT
    xyz
FROM
    col_admin 
WHERE
    qq = ''
    AND (ab LIKE 'some1' 
    OR ab LIKE 'some2' 
    OR ab LIKE 'some3')
```