# Select Data Last 30 Days Not Work Using Or

Tags: sql

i'm try to get data last by 30 days, and then i'm order this by hit because i want to get last 30 days data trending.

```
SELECT *, 
       category.title AS nama_kategori 
FROM   category 
       join posting 
         ON category.alias = posting.id_category 
WHERE  DATE BETWEEN Now() - interval 30 day AND Now() 
       AND id_category LIKE '%gga%' 
        OR id_category LIKE '%wstb%' 
ORDER  BY posting.hit DESC
```

the output of this query is there the data is not las by 30 days ( since 1 oct ) there the other data that have other years.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYlEs.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your OR query `id_category LIKE '%wstb%'`  which will  return all entries with that category regardless of your date query .

**Add parenthesis on AND query and pass multiple OR conditions**

```
SELECT *, 
       category.title AS nama_kategori 
FROM   category 
       join posting 
         ON category.alias = posting.id_category 
WHERE  DATE BETWEEN Now() - interval 30 day AND Now() 
       AND (id_category LIKE '%gga%' 
        OR id_category LIKE '%wstb%') 
ORDER  BY posting.hit DESC
```