# error whlite using multiple or & and conditions in hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

hi I have a table as below 
temp_layer_table:-

```
id    count    name
1      0       v
2      3       r
1      5       t
4      0       f
4      6       g
2      0       r
3      6       r
3      0       g
5      0       t
```

now I need to write a condition where if id is 1 or 4 or 3 and count = 0 for all 3 ids then i should eliminate those records

```
id    count    name
2      3       r
1      5       t
4      6       g
2      0       r
3      6       r
5      0       t
```

I have tried below hive query but does't work

code 1:-

```
insert into table final_layer_table 
select n.*
  from temp_layer_table n 
 where id = '1' 
   or  id = '4' 
   or  id = '3' 
  and count != '0' ;
```

code2:-

```
 insert into table final_layer_table 
 select n.*
   from temp_layer_table n 
  where id in ('1','4','3') 
    and count != '0' ;
```

Comment: `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. I.e. `where id = '1' or  id = '4' or  id = '3' and count != '0'` means `where id = '1' or  id = '4' or  (id = '3' and count != '0')`... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or

Comment: Given that both queries would result in a syntax error, I'm not quite sure what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if id is 1 or 4 or 3 and count = 0 for all 3 ids then i should eliminate those records

I would phrase this with a `not` condition:

```
where not (id in (1, 3, 4) and count = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want rows where either:

- The ids are not 1, 3, 4; or
- count <> 0.

That would be:

```
where id not iN (1, 3, 4) or
      count <> 0
```