# Are inner parenthesis needed in the WHERE clause? or anywhere

Tags: sql, sql-server, parentheses

In the WHERE section or anywhere really where you have multiple conditions like OR's I know outer parenthesis are required but are the inner ones?

For example my assumption is that

```
WHERE A.Title='EMP'
AND ( (A.NAME='Mike') OR (A.ID='9001') )
```

Is the same as writing

```
WHERE A.Title='EMP'
AND ( A.NAME='Mike' OR A.ID='9001' )
```

However if we remove the outer parenthesis then I know the query will be different.

Example:

```
WHERE A.Title='EMP'
AND (A.NAME='Mike') OR (A.ID='9001')
```

And

```
WHERE A.Title='EMP'
AND A.NAME='Mike' OR A.ID='9001'
```

Are both the same thing but not at all what we want.

Is there any chance that data will be evaluated different between the first 2 conditions?

Comment: *"Is there any chance that data will be evaluated different between the 2 conditions?"* No. Wrapping a single boolean expression inside parenthesis changes nothing.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks. I was told something else and had to be sure.

Comment: (1) They are the same and you could drop the parens totally.  (2) This logic should be in the `ON` clause not in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you are correct I just threw this in. The question also applies to contions like `A.NAME = 'Mike'`

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my question to make more since in the where clause

Comment: `WHERE A.NAME='Mike' OR A.ID='9001'`, SQL is not Lisp.

Comment: @jarlh Lisp? I am not familiar with that word

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)

Comment: @Mike-SMT `I was told something else` what exactly? It may not be about what you think. `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` in binary logic, so in almost all languages `A OR B AND C` is not the same as `(A OR B) AND C`. It's no different than addition and multiplication in math. Even the same symbols are used, eg `+` for OR

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was told "I want it to evaluate the `AND` statements before the `OR` statements" and the claim was that the inner paren's were needed for order of operations

Comment: Please, recommended view this top about [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or)

Comment: @AntonioLeonardo thanks I am reading it now and will forward it on.

Comment: @Mike-SMT in that case, double no. The parentheses are needed when you want to evaluate `OR` before `AND`. I had quite a few queries that returned unexpected results when I added an `OR` and forgot the parentheses, precisely because AND takes precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's like in math

```
2 + 3 * 4   ==> 14
```

is the same as

```
2 + (3 * 4)   ==> 14
```

because the multiplication has a higher precedence than the addition. If you want to do the addition before the multiplication, you must add parenthesis.

```
(2 + 3) * 4   ==> 20
```

In SQL `AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`. `=` as comparison operator has a higher precedence than both of them. Therefore the inner parenthesis are not required, because the `=` will always be performed first. E.g.

```
A.Title='EMP' AND A.NAME='Mike' OR A.ID='9001'
```

is the same as

```
((A.Title='EMP') AND (A.NAME='Mike')) OR (A.ID='9001')
```

Parenthesis are only required if you want to perform the `OR` before the `AND` (even when it appears first in the expression):

```
A.Title='EMP' AND (A.NAME='Mike' OR A.ID='9001')
```

Only when operators have the same precedence, they are evaluated left to right.

For the full precedence list, see: [Operator Precedence (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Correct I knew that. The person was saying the inner paren's were needed to evaluate OR first. like this `AND ( (A.NAME='Mike') OR (A.ID='9001') )` and I disagreed but of coarse had to question if I was wrong so I posted on SO :D

Comment: Though not needed, clarity is important, so you may put them in for readability on more complicated clauses (especially where ANDs and ORs are mixed, you may get what you want without any parens, but you should attempt to be clear for future readers).