# Case When and or Statement producing different results

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a count statement, I want one condition to be equal and two not equal.
If I query country and user_tag separately, I get 0 rows but If I query same time like below I get 10 rows.

What am I doing wrong

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN 
    n.country != o.country 
    OR n.user_tag != o.user_tag
    AND n.email_address = o.email_address THEN n.email_address
    END) AS OTHER_CHANGES_IN_DATA
FROM OLD o
INNER JOIN NEW n 
    ON n.user_id = o.user_id
```

If both country and user_tag is ran like this the results should be 0

Comment: Please update your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve, based on that data

Comment: you are counting email, so count teh email in old and new and what your join makes it takes every userid fromold and combines it with every userid id new, that can make a lot of unwanted columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question not quite clear, so I'm assuming you mean that both

```sql
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN 
    n.user_tag != o.user_tag
    AND n.email_address = o.email_address THEN n.email_address
    END) AS OTHER_CHANGES_IN_DATA
FROM OLD o
INNER JOIN NEW n 
    ON n.user_id = o.user_id
```

```sql
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN 
    n.country != o.country 
    AND n.email_address = o.email_address THEN n.email_address
    END) AS OTHER_CHANGES_IN_DATA
FROM OLD o
INNER JOIN NEW n 
    ON n.user_id = o.user_id
```

return 0, but query you cited in your question returns 10 for some user.

If my assumption correct, than I believe I can explain your problem: `AND` takes precedence over `OR` in your case statement. So conditions of this two query not really correlated to condition of yours. More about OR and AND in SQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241158/21363224).

Regarding your query: try

```
... WHEN 
    (n.country != o.country 
    OR n.user_tag != o.user_tag)
    AND n.email_address = o.email_address THEN ...
```