# Mysql query for employee assignments when peer(s) are absent

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a mysql table with the following structure:

| Assign | Pri | Sec | Ter | Qua |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Tom | Mark | Sally | Tammy |
| 60 | Sally | Ace | Tom | Mark |
| 170 | Mark | Sally | Ace | Tammy |
| 220 | Ace | Tammy | Tom | Sally |
| 17 | Tammy | Sally | Mark | Ace |
| 439 | Sally | Tom | Tammy | Mark |

I want to display the employees assignments based on primary assignments and if there are any absences, based on their status as secondary, tertiary or quaternary. So for Sally, her assignments are 60 and 439 every day. But if Tom and Mark are absent, her assignments would be 60, 439, 21 and 170. What I have only pulls assignments based on if Sally is secondary, tertiary or quaternary but doesn't take into account if, when Sally is tertiary or quaternary, if the person in front of them (secondary or tertiary) is in the office and has taken that assignment. So with my query, she would get assignments, 60, 439, 21, 170, 220 and 17.

This is what I have so far that doesn't have the logic I need.

```
SELECT
    Assign
FROM
    assign_table
WHERE
    Pri = 'Tom'
    AND
    sec = 'Sally'
    OR
    pri = 'Tom'
    AND
    ter = 'Sally'
    OR
    pri = 'Tom'
    AND qua = 'Sally'
    OR
    pri = 'Sally'
ORDER BY
    Assign;
```

I should mention I have another table with employee names and an absent column that contains 0 or 1 if they are in the office or absent that particular day (employee_credentials).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your table design is denormalized....

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause is kinda messed-up - you need to carefully group your clauses with your `OR` and `AND`  operators and understand operator precedence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or

Comment: We can help you best if you show us an example of the other table's data, and the desired result of your query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Join the `assign_table` and `employee_credentials` and use the conditional logic to determine the assignments based on absence of status of other employees. May be this code would work

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
JOIN employee_credentials e ON a.Pri = e.EmployeeName
WHERE e.Absent = 0
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
JOIN employee_credentials e ON a.Sec = e.EmployeeName
WHERE e.Absent = 0
AND a.Pri NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM employee_credentials WHERE Absent = 0)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
JOIN employee_credentials e ON a.Ter = e.EmployeeName
WHERE e.Absent = 0
AND a.Pri NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM employee_credentials WHERE Absent = 0)
AND a.Sec NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM employee_credentials WHERE Absent = 0)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
JOIN employee_credentials e ON a.Qua = e.EmployeeName
WHERE e.Absent = 0
AND a.Pri NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM employee_credentials WHERE Absent = 0)
AND a.Sec NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM employee_credentials WHERE Absent = 0)
AND a.Ter NOT IN (SELECT EmployeeName FROM employee_credentials WHERE Absent = 0)
ORDER BY Assign;
```

we can use UNION to combine.
Thanks

Comment: His answer didn't provide the output described, but it going me headed in the right direction and with a few changes I was able to get what I wanted. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL ≥ 8.0.14, you can use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` to unpivot the data in `assign_table`. See [Lateral Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html).

Assuming your `employee_credentials` table looks like this:

| EmployeeName | Dt | Absent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ace | 2023-09-17 | 0 |
| Mark | 2023-09-17 | 1 |
| Sally | 2023-09-17 | 0 |
| Tammy | 2023-09-17 | 0 |
| Tom | 2023-09-17 | 1 |

You can use the following query to unpivot `assign_table` and join to `employee_credentials` to determine whether the employee is absent, or not. You then use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to assign a new priority for each assignment.

```sql
WITH assign_not_absent AS (
    SELECT a.Assign, x.EmployeeName, x.Priority, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Assign ORDER BY x.Priority) AS NewPriority
    FROM assign_table a
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT Pri, 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT Sec, 2 UNION ALL
        SELECT Ter, 3 UNION ALL
        SELECT Qua, 4
    ) x (EmployeeName, Priority)
    JOIN employee_credentials ec
        ON x.EmployeeName = ec.EmployeeName
        AND ec.Absent = 0
        AND ec.Dt = '2023-09-17'
)
SELECT * FROM assign_not_absent WHERE NewPriority = 1 AND EmployeeName = 'Sally';
```

Output:

| Assign | EmployeeName | Priority | NewPriority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Sally | 3 | 1 |
| 60 | Sally | 1 | 1 |
| 170 | Sally | 2 | 1 |
| 439 | Sally | 1 | 1 |

---

If you are using an older version of MySQL (< 8.0.14), another option is to join to employee_credentials multiple times:

```sql
SELECT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
JOIN employee_credentials cPri ON a.Pri = cPri.EmployeeName AND cPri.Dt = CURRENT_DATE
JOIN employee_credentials cSec ON a.Sec = cSec.EmployeeName AND cSec.Dt = CURRENT_DATE
JOIN employee_credentials cTer ON a.Ter = cTer.EmployeeName AND cTer.Dt = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE Pri = 'Sally'
  OR (Sec = 'Sally' AND cPri.Absent = 1)
  OR (Ter = 'Sally' AND cPri.Absent = 1 AND cSec.Absent = 1)
  OR (Qua = 'Sally' AND cPri.Absent = 1 AND cSec.Absent = 1 AND cTer.Absent = 1)
ORDER BY a.Assign;
```

Output:

| Assign |
| --- |
| 21 |
| 60 |
| 170 |
| 439 |

---

Another approach which will work on any version, similar to that suggested by Aditya:

```sql
SELECT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
WHERE Pri = 'Sally'

UNION ALL

SELECT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
WHERE Sec = 'Sally'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_credentials WHERE EmployeeName = a.Pri AND Dt = CURRENT_DATE AND Absent = 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
WHERE Ter = 'Sally'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_credentials WHERE EmployeeName = a.Pri AND Dt = CURRENT_DATE AND Absent = 1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_credentials WHERE EmployeeName = a.Sec AND Dt = CURRENT_DATE AND Absent = 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT a.Assign
FROM assign_table a
WHERE Qua = 'Sally'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_credentials WHERE EmployeeName = a.Pri AND Dt = CURRENT_DATE AND Absent = 1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_credentials WHERE EmployeeName = a.Sec AND Dt = CURRENT_DATE AND Absent = 1)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM employee_credentials WHERE EmployeeName = a.Ter AND Dt = CURRENT_DATE AND Absent = 1)

ORDER BY Assign;
```

---

Your `assign_table` holds an unnormalised ordered many-to-many relationship between employees and tasks/assignments, so a better structure might look like:

`employees`

| id | name | other_columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ace | ... |
| 2 | Mark | ... |
| 3 | Sally | ... |
| 4 | Tammy | ... |
| 5 | Tom | ... |

`assignments_employees`

| assignment_id | employee_id | priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 5 | 1 |
| 21 | 2 | 2 |
| 21 | 3 | 3 |
| 21 | 4 | 4 |
| 60 | 3 | 1 |
| etc |  |  |

`employee_absence`

| employee_id | dt | absent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-17 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-09-17 | 1 |
| 3 | 2023-09-17 | 0 |
| 4 | 2023-09-17 | 0 |
| 5 | 2023-09-17 | 1 |

With this structure the query becomes:

```sql
WITH assign_not_absent AS (
    SELECT ae.assignment_id, ae.employee_id, ae.priority, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ae.assignment_id ORDER BY ae.priority) AS new_priority
    FROM assignments_employees ae
    JOIN employee_absence ea
        ON ae.employee_id = ea.employee_id
        AND ea.absent = 0
        AND ea.dt = '2023-09-17'
)
SELECT ana.assignment_id, e.name, ana.priority, ana.new_priority
FROM assign_not_absent ana
JOIN employees e
    ON ana.employee_id = e.id
WHERE ana.new_priority = 1
AND e.name = 'Sally';
```

Output:

| assignment_id | name | priority | new_priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Sally | 3 | 1 |
| 60 | Sally | 1 | 1 |
| 170 | Sally | 2 | 1 |
| 439 | Sally | 1 | 1 |

The CTEs in both of these queries can be made more efficient by restricting assignments to those to which Sally is already assigned.

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jlAgr-9I) to play around with.

Whichever approach you decide to work with, make sure you do some testing with a large enough dataset. A query *"working fine"* with a test dataset of a few dozen rows, may behave very differently with a few hundred thousand rows.