# Conditional WHERE and clause help in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have a WHERE statement in my report that lists what I need pulled from a table,

```
 WHERE
  PrimaryAction= '308'
  AND PrimaryAction= '309'
  AND PrimaryAction= '307
  AND SecondaryAction= '308'
```

etc.

One, it isn't pulling just those instances. I can't figure out what is wrong. Or is there a way to combine/condense this?

Two, can I do it and have it say something like,
PrimaryAction= '308' '309' '307 , THEN 'Yes' so that in my report it just prints out yes if that is the case?

I tried combining them, there is Primary, Secondary , and Tertiary for the same codes but it just didn't pull anything when I ran it. It wouldn't even run when I tried to change to say Yes.

Answer (score 0):

the condition can't be 308,307 and 309 at the same time

So you can do.

but be reminded

> The SQL Server AND operator takes precedence over the SQL Server OR operator (just like a multiplication operation takes precedence over an addition operation).

see [SQL Logic Operator Precedence: And and Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or) for more example and explanation

```
 WHERE
  (PrimaryAction= '308'
  'OR PrimaryAction= '309'
  OR PrimaryAction= '307')
  AND SecondaryAction= '308'
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked. Is there a way to have it say if it is 307, OR 308 or 309 then YES?

Comment: for that you must add to then SELECT a conditional column LIKE CASE WHEN PrimaryAction = '308' Then 'frst number' ....

Comment: Actually that didn't work. The Report Builder pulled the Primary but not the Secondary or Tertiary into the report. And only for 307.

Comment: you didn't read the linked article, for my where clause you get only 308 if secondary is also 308, the same goes for 309

Comment: So there is no way to get it pull only 307, 308 and 309 from all three if they all don't have it?

Comment: it is hard to understand the problem, without seeing the data and wanted result,

Comment: It's a heatlhcare report for Restraints. It pulls from an Incident Report in our EHR. However not every Incident results in Restraints, only those coded with 307, 308, 309. I need a report that detects only those codes, whether it was the first , second , or third action that staff took. I tried to put it in the WHERE clause in my stored procedure, but it was pulling everything. Maybe there's another solution? I thought calculated field but I couldn't find the configuration I needed to for the expression. I'm new at report building.

Comment: you can do `    Select * FROM Tab
      
      where PrimaryAction IN ( '308' ,'309'  , '307')
      or  SecondaryAction IN ( '308' ,'309'  , '307')
      or  Thirdn IN ( '308' ,'309'  , '307')`

Comment: That didn't work. Report builder doesn't seem to like IN

Comment: thenyou need `select * FROM Tab
  
  where PrimaryAction = '308'
  OR PrimaryAction= '309'
  OR PrimaryAction= '307'
  or  SecondaryAction = '308' 
  or  SecondaryAction = '307'
  or  SecondaryAction = '309'
  or  Thirdn = '308' 
  or  ThirdAction = '307'
  or  ThirdAction = '309'`