What are the rules for interpreting "logically ambiguous" queries in Yii2?
In Yii2, you can add clauses to queries such as:
Product::find()
->where(['name' => 'MyProd'])
->andWhere(['type' => 'Toy'])
->orWhere(['category' => 'MyCat'])
->andWhere(['location' => 'MyLoc'])

How is this interpreted? Is it that it finds products that

are called 'MyProd' and have type 'Toy'

or

are in category 'MyCat' and have location 'MyLoc'
?

Is it that it finds products which :

are called 'My Prod'

and

have Type 'Toy' or are in category 'MyCat'

and

have location 'MyLoc'?

Is it something else entirely? Is there a general rule that can be described easily for how such "logically ambiguous" queries are interpreted?

Assuming no parentheses are added in the generated SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241142/sql-logic-operator-precedence-and-and-or

So in my case it would be the first option. Thank you. Just one more question: what happens if I start with an orWhere instead of where? This first or basically gets ignored, right?

If you don't have an existing condition, orWhere and andWhere act just like where. Click on the "Source code" link in the documentation

Thank you. Somebody with closing privileges can close this question if they so wish.

Neither of your interpretation is correct.
The correct interpretation would be that it finds products that:
 1. Have location "MyLoc"
   and 
 2.1. Have category "MyCat"
     or
 2.2. Have name "MyProd" and type "Type"

This is because when andWhere() and orWhere() methods are called, they take existing conditions and add new condition to existing conditions using and/or.
So, if you rewrite your methods call into single complex array condition you will get:
[
    'and',
    [
        'or',
        [
            'and',
            ['name' => 'MyProd'],
            ['type' => 'Toy'],
        ],
        ['category' => 'MyCat'],
    ],
    ['location' => 'MyLoc'],
]

Translated into MySQL condition you will get:
((name = "MyProd" AND type = "Toy") OR category = 'MyCat') AND location = 'MyLoc'


So, just to confirm, it builds a hierarchy in which the highest order term is determined by the LAST "where" condition in the query, not by the first? I'm asking because it seems rather counterintuitive that the last term ends up having the highest precedence in the hierarchy.

Pretty much yes. It might seem counterintuitive if you think about set of andWhere() and orWhere() calls together. But it makes sense if you think about each call independently where each call should only be able to add to existing condition. It should not be able to change existing condition. This is necessary because the query can be passed around through multiple components before being executed. And each component should be able to add its condition without need to know what existing conditions are like.
